# SSIS package random failures when running parallel

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS parent package that runs multiple child packages.  The child packages run directly off SQL Server.

If I run the process in serial MaxConcurrentExecutables = -1 the process works as expected.  If I run in parallel, I get random failures with the error `Error 0xC0014062. Failed to load the package` "" from server "".  The failures are random in that child package 1 could fail on run 1, but be successful in run 2, but child package 2 would fail etc.

When this happens, if I stop the process and run that package it works fine.

I have tried changing "RetainSameConnection" to false and true without any luck.  There isn't much more information in the error apart from the package address. I have also tried changing the DelayValidation, true false (for each package and container).

I know that each individual package works as the master package and children will run serially, but not in parallel.

The SQL Server is 2014, I am developing in VS 2019.

Any ideas or thoughts on why this could be happening?

Comment: Best guess is that your server might be too busy to service the request but that feels like a stretch. Just to tease out some detail, when you say " child packages run directly off SQL Server" what does that mean to you? How do you run the child SSIS packages? If Execute Package Task, then how is that configured? When you go parallel, how many child packages could be launched? Is this using Project deployment model (SSISDB) or Package Deployment model (msdb, file system)?

Comment: Hey, so my “Master” executes several package tasks that are external referenced to a SQL Server where the child package is located.  The number of child packages is 10.  It’s a dev server and is never busy.  It’s a package deployment. Thank you.

Comment: It does feel like some sort of race condition, but not from a coding perspective, more of a connection issue maybe.

Comment: Same master package runs 100% serially, zero issues.

Comment: Package execution, check. You run the child packages using - Execute Package Task. It's using a SQL Connection. Is the child package server the same as the master or is it different? If different, is there anything "weird" about it? Amazon RDS, different geography from master server, changing authentication, etc?

Comment: Exactly the same server.  It's strange that if I run it serially, they all just work, but when running in parallel I get random package failures.  If I run in parallel a package will rail, Is top the process, and run that package individually, works great.  Would it be battling for connections, too many connections?

Comment: I was thinking about moving all the packages locally inside the project (instead of pointing the execute package to the server), but how would I deploy them to the package store.  At the moment my "Master" points to the various package paths on the server.  If I bring them down locally, how can I deploy the package so it knows it's "local" any ideas?